# Quantile extrapolation?

Tags: estimation, quantiles, extreme-value

Suppose you wanted to estimate the $q$ quantile of a distribution by observing $n$ independent draws from that distribution, but with $q < \frac{1}{n}$. What methods are available, and for what ranges of the 'undersampling coefficient' $q n$ are they expected to work?

I can imagine some parametric approaches: a fully parametric approach would assume the form of the distribution, then fit *e.g.* the scale and location, and estimate the quantile from the fitted distribution.  A slightly less parametric form would try to estimate the form (*e.g.* fit to a power law) of the left tail, and use that to extrapolate. Are either of these sensible? Do they work? What are some other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are also interested in quantiles with $q>1-1/n$ there is no definitive answer. You need to supply more details, since for distributions with heavy tails the estimation of such quantiles involves quite complicated mathematics. Try google search for tail index estimation and you will get plethora of links.

Comment: This is equivalent to my problem, but it is easier to pose the problem in terms of the left tail (smaller quantiles).